# android studio manifest error in category

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

Hi i have moved from Eclipse to android studio and I found a bit of a bug where in when i change the original Manifest and add other activities like so

[image]

and when i change it into this the program error and i cant launch or debugged he program

the first box contains the error when i change the value into .LAUNCHER and . DEFAULT,

The box with the black container that i changed was the newly added java class and i adjusted the category name into the .LAUNCHER

the last box which was the original and was the .LAUNCHER now the .DEFAULT because it will be the menu later

[image]

now i cant even run the application and when i change back to the original it is solved but i need to changed it, can anybody help with this one and thanks!

also this is the main error and not in the logcat when i try to run this shows up, also i highlighted the area

[image]

Comment: Which error exactly are you getting? Please provide a full error message from logcat.

Comment: hi i have edited and added the error that shows up when i run the application